# Create swagger.json in java/scala

Tags: swagger

I would like to create valid `swagger.json` file in runtime. The brute force approach would be to model whole sagger spec in my program and then just build the `swagger.json` by hand taking all responsibility of the validity on me.

My question is: is there any library or parts of swagger itself, that can help me? I don't want to generate the file based on some existing server code, but rather create it and output as string in runtime.

Comment: Take a look to this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340330/generate-yaml-or-json-file-from-swagger-documentation/34636944#34636944](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340330/generate-yaml-or-json-file-from-swagger-documentation/34636944#34636944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unclear what you're after, but I'm guessing it's one of the following.

1. You can create a POJO and render it as a swagger JSON or YAML description.  To do this, simply use the [swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) and write it with Json.pretty(swaggerPojo) or Yaml.pretty(swaggerPojo).  Then you're *almost* guaranteed a valid swagger definition, although it's not for sure, as you can programmatically build things that are invalid.  Structurally, though, you should be fine.
2. You can generate *new* server code using a variety of library integrations as listed in [http://swagger.io/tools](http://swagger.io/tools/).  These can use code annotations, comments, etc. to automatically generate the swagger definition.

Comment: Sorry for unclearness, I mean point 1. Thanks for answer but swagger-core is huuuge, is there any example how to do this? I mean, what classes from this huge codebase I should use.

Comment: Add swagger-models as a dependency then you can use simple builder methods for the POJOS.  Swagger-models is not a big code base, there are 75 simple models in there which represent the entire OAI specification.